# How to insert content in a header of web page from other file?

Tags: php

I have a problem with an included header in a phtml file.
I have an MVC project and the view file is builded like this

```
<?php
  require_once'header.phtml';

  //SOME PHP COMMAND TO PRINT SOME STUFF

  reuire_once 'footer.phtml';
?>
```

When I press F12 in Google Chrome the header content apears in the body of the page, like this :

```
  <html>
<head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title></title>
           <style type="text/css"></style></head>
        <body>           
                    <title>UserList</title>
                    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
                    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/Mystyle.css">
                    <meta name="description" content="MVC MiniShop Project">
                    <meta name="keywords" content="MVC Online Store">
                    <meta name="author" content="Vasile Vetisan">
                    <meta charset="UTF-8">  
            <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
        <br style="clear:left">
    </div>USER LIST IS:<br> <table border="1"><tbody><tr><td>USER_ID</td><td>FIRST_NAME</td><td>LAST_NAME</td><td>USERNAME</td><td>EMAIL</td><td>PASSWORD</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>Test</td><td>Unu</td><td>test1</td><td>test1@gmail.com</td></td></tr></tbody></table>

</body></html>
```

Even if I change the structure of the ViewUser page like this:

```
<html>
<header>
<?php
   require_once 'header.phtml'
?>
</header>
 <body>
     //SOME GENERATED STUFF WITH PHP
 </body>
</html>
```

The result is the same as previous :( .
So  as summary of my post I need a method to insert content in header of a phtml page from another page using php or phphtml extenxions.
I have tried a lot of stuff so I need some new ideas or answers.

Comment: Shouldn't you change <header> to <head>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the very good, easy and effective way of including parts is using php, where part.html is file with your code.

```
 <?php
 include "part.html";
 ?>
```

Example:

**part.html**

```
<p> Hello world! </p>
```

**index.php**

```
<body>
<?php
include "part.html";
?>
</body>
```

**output should be**

```
<body>
<p> Hello World! </p>
</body>
```

Comment: Stepo I don't undersand what U want to say

Comment: I want to show you including other files into page as you need. I think it's example you need, isn't it?

Comment: I don't think that U get it. I will edit my question to make it clear

Comment: http://www.zfforums.com/zend-framework-components-13/model-view-controller-mvc-21/any-way-include-phtml-files-other-files-1168.html

Comment: I want to include a file that contains head conent into head of another file. But my head content apears in body

Comment: I figured out last night, it is a bug in my MVC project, I have an Autoload function and it seems that the extra head section of html page comes from there. U were right, your answer was correct, I know how to include a PHP file into another, but my error came from the fact that I had actually two head section declared, I forgot about the first section and voila a naughty bug was born. Thanks for your effort.